# Failing Seagate HDD - Not Recognised

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I am having a look at a friend's computer which contains a 500GB Seagate HDD. Unfortunately the HDD is not recognised by the BIOS menu and it beeps 11 times upon powerup. I've moved the HDD to another laptop but the problem remains. I've downloaded SeaTools for DOS (Seagate's Diagnostic tool) but unfortunately to no avail and the disc remains unseen when using this DOS boot disc.

The HDD is only 6 months old so I'm very surprised at this but it appears a common problem with Seagate 2.5" HDDs as well as other HDDs manufactured by Seagate. I intend to try it in an external caddy on Thursday when back in work and also through a forensic writeblocker but just wondering if anyone has any other suggestions? I am of the opinion it is some chip on the HDD board which prevents it spinning due to a fault. If so, I've lost to deactivate this just so I can simply recover the data on the drive and start with a new disc.

Thanks

Comment: This question is not a programming question, making it off-topic here on Stack Overflow. I am voting to migrate to Super User, where it might be acceptable.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow. Please take a few minutes to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) so you'll know what types of questions are (and are not) appropriate to ask here. Keeping things on-topic is one of the ways we can help SO remain a useful programming resource. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies folks. As 'harddrive' was a tag, I assumed I could ask this. Apologies again

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother, the HD is lost. If it's still under warranty send it back to the manufacturer.

Comment: *nods*.  RMA the drive. If it is no longer under warranty get a new drive. In both cases reinstall from your backup.